# Is there a language learning log app? (Strava or MyFitnessPal, but for learning languages)

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources

On [Strava](https://www.strava.com/), you can log your exercise.  On [MyFitnessPal](https://www.google.com/search?q=MyFitnessPal), you can log your diet.  But I want to log my language learning efforts.

I'm learning Chinese so I'd like to be able to:

- log time spent reading, writing, watching news, movies, etc.
- log time spent with my teacher,
- upload photos of my Chinese handwriting,
- upload articles that I've written in Chinese.

It'd be nice to keep track of the hours I'm putting in, and see how I'm improving over time.  It'd also be nice to be able to share it with other language-learning enthusiasts for mutual motivation.

The closest I've found thus far is [SeeSaw](https://web.seesaw.me/), but this seems more for classrooms.

**Question**: Is there a language learning log app?

Comment: Not aware of any apps, but something like an [Evernote template](https://evernote.com/templates) might work for you. It does require Evernote Plus, though. ($8/month)

Comment: I wonder whether spending time in a target language country merits anything more than keeping track of new vocabulary and grammar forms.

Answer (score 3):

I've built Lingo Journal to keep a log of my language learning activities. You can find it an https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teraculus.lingojournalandroid&hl=en&gl=US
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Recently launched a site that does just this — [Lingotrack](https://lingotrack.com).

You can track ‘activity hours’, time spent consuming specific foreign media in your library, and even write journals. Should be just what you’re looking for!

Comment: I started using this a week ago ([here](https://lingotrack.com/profile/becky82)'s my profile.  I really enjoy seeing what other people are studying.

Answer (score 1):

I asked/ranted about this [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/jhoe7z/i_wish_there_was_an_app_where_i_could_log_my/); I was a bit surprised how unpopular this idea is.  They gave me two reasonable suggestions:

1. [Polylogger](https://polylogger.com/) (see also: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/polylogger)) where its possible to log language study.  It's looks like it's exactly what I want, but at this stage it's underdeveloped.

   > [image: Polylogger screenshot]
   > <sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>
2. [Toggl](http://toggl.com) (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toggl_Track)) is a general time-tracking application/webpage, but not specifically designed for learning languages.  There's a number of reviews on YouTube, such as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWeQxGU1iiE) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxhmagOw9pY).

Comment: I'm currently working on a tracking app specific to language-learning, as I've also found PolyLogger to be undeveloped and other options to be too general. Your Reddit post was removed; do you have any features suggestions/advice you could share here?

Comment: I've been using Toggl since then, and it's been fine.  My main advice would be not to make it too complicated, so as to not obstruct studying.  Also, Toggl doesn't seem to have an easy way to create screenshots to share with people.